# Magento Listing all categories with thumbnail

Tags: magento

i use one code to show all the categories and thumbs, works fine, but shows in list
There is some way to show one on side another? like the products show in the pages

```
<ul> <?php $children =
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(2); // put your main
root category id here foreach ($children as $category):
$category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
echo '<li><a href="' . $category->getUrl() . '">' .
$category->getName() . '</a></li>'; ?> <img src="<?php echo
Mage::getBaseUrl('media')?>catalog/category/<?php echo
$category->getThumbnail() ?>" height="100" width='100'> <?php 
$children =
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
foreach ($children as $category):
$category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
echo '<li><a href="' . $category->getUrl() . '">' .
$category->getName() . '</a></li>'; ?> <img src="<?php echo
Mage::getBaseUrl('media')?>catalog/category/<?php echo
$category->getThumbnail() ?>" height="100" width='100'>

<?php  $children =
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
foreach ($children as $category):
$category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
echo '<li><a href="' . $category->getUrl() . '">' .
$category->getName() . '</a></li>'; ?> <img src="<?php echo
Mage::getBaseUrl('media')?>catalog/category/<?php echo
$category->getThumbnail() ?>" height="100" width='100'> <?php
endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>


<?php endforeach; ?> </ul>
```

Comment: Are you trying to show the products in list view style of grid ? just like default magento style.

Comment: I want show the categories in Grid style,im testing in this page  http://www.lojaotaku.com.br/about-magento-demo-store

Comment: If you want to show products in grid view.please have a look on base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml.The page contain both list and grid code.if still problem inform me.

Comment: Hello Mahmood ! I want show the Categories in Grid style in the CMS page, do you know some way to do that? i search in many places, but i could find a way to do that in magento 1.7 Thanks!!

Comment: yes why not you can do it.you can override the product block .you can check my extension on http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-add-products-to-cms.html.i am not always here so contact me for details on email or chat.